# Using MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK in Google Cloud Speech API(Android App)

Tags: java, android, api, android-mediarecorder, google-speech-api

I'm developing an Android app that displays the text of voice of other party who's in the phone call. I'm using [Google Cloud Speech API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech). I think I've two options:

1. Record Audio of other person(in regular intervals) and send it through API as InputStream and receive the corresponding text.
2. Change [this line](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/Speech/app/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/android/speech/VoiceRecorder.java#L161) of code to something like `MediaSource.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK`with proper AudioFormat Encodings.

In the first case, `mApi` object in `SpeechService.java` is becoming null (Although in `onPostExcute()` method, `mApi` isn't null. I'm sure I'm calling `recognizeInputStream()` method after mApi is assigned. I don't know what's wrong here.

In the second case, I don't know if it possible to change AudioSource from MIC to VOICE_DOWNLINK(I got `Invalid Audio Source` Error, when I changed). If it's possible, I don't know proper AudioFormat settings (like Channel and Encoding). Do I have to direct BroadcastReceiver method to make this case possible?

Comment: What kind of app are you developing? According to the doc (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_DOWNLINK), VOICE_DOWNLINK is not intended to be used by 3rd party application. Some people report that it works, though (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606029/android-call-recording-using-voice-uplink-and-voice-downlink).

Comment: 1. kind of app?? I'm just developing for myself(no background server). I just want to use the source of VOICE_DOWNLINK as an input to Synchronous Speech Recognition instead of MIC.

Comment: @YuichiAraki
2. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606029/android-call-recording-using-voice-uplink-and-voice-downlink) you gave doesn't help. I've created a BroadcastReceiver file and instantiated the Recorder object when my phone state goes to OFFHOOK. I believe VoiceRecorder file in Speech API for Android is more elegant than the answer in that link.